# Include TeX in Roxygen comments

Tags: r, tex, roxygen2, roxygen

I want to use TeX in Roxygen comments.

E.g.,

```
#' @title   $f(y|\theta)$
#'
#'@description  
#'
#'  \begin{eqnarray*}
#'         a + b &=& c \\
#'         a + b &=& c \\
#'         \theta &=& \beta \\
#'  \end{eqnarray*}
#'
#'
#'@references  
#'@param  
#'@importFrom 
#'@seealso  
#'@inheritParams
```

Is there some methods such that the PDF manual reflects TeX scripts in Roxygen comments .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `eqn` for inline equations: `\eqn{f(x|theta)}`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998615/equations-in-r-package-documentation-do-not-work/54998769#54998769) about how to document an inline equation for PDF, HTML and ASCII.

Use `deqn` for equations in blocks. I don't think that the environment `eqnarray` is available, but the `array` environment is available:

```
\deqn{\begin{array}[ccc] a + b &=& c \\ a + b &=& c \\ \theta &=& \beta \end{array}}
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the codes!! I did not know the script `\eqn`, which somewhat differ my intuitive, e.g.,  \eqn{\sigma^2} 
 is not my desired 
 output. but I try to use it for my PDF manual. I think direct edition of the TeX file transformed from Roxygen is one way but I do not know whether such edition is permitted or not when I upload to CRAN.  REF: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397607/can-r-help-manuals-have-latex-math-in-them