# R help pages with multiline LaTeX equations

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I am writing R package documentation with `roxygen2`. I want to insert the following multiline equation into a help page, but my LaTeX code is not being rendered.

[image]

```
#' hello2
#'
#' @description
#' \deqn{
#' F(t)= \begin{cases}\alpha(t) f_{L}(t)+[1-\alpha(t)] f_{C}(t) & t_{L}<t<t_{C} \\ \beta(t) f_{C}(t)+[1-\beta(t)] f_{R}(t) & t_{C}<t<t_{R}\end{cases}
#' }
#' 
#' @export
hello2 <- function() {}
```

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397607/can-r-help-manuals-have-latex-math-in-them or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54998615/equations-in-r-package-documentation-do-not-work. The RStudio help viewer uses the HTML markup which does not seem to support LaTeX formatting.

Comment: I noticed those links. But still cannot figure out the solution for my case

Comment: The point of those links is that it's not possible `cases` is not a base LaTeX function. It comes from the AMS styles and therefore cannot be used. See also https://colinfay.me/writing-r-extensions/writing-r-documentation-files.html#Mathematics

Comment: Yes, `Rd` macros `\eqn` and `\deqn` do not support `cases`. However, it _is_ possible to have that equation rendered in the HTML help using macros provided by package [`mathjaxr`](https://github.com/wviechtb/mathjaxr), which embeds MathJax. You'll need to add `mathjaxr` as a dependency of your package...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### New answer

Support for KaTeX in HTML rendering of Rd files was added in R 4.2.0.  Support for amsmath in PDF rendering of Rd files was added in R 4.2.2.  Hence packages with `Depends: R (>= 4.3)` can safely specify multiline equations using `\deqn`.  No need for **mathjaxr**.

---

### Original answer

Just to demonstrate that it's possible once you've integrated [**mathjaxr**](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=mathjaxr) correctly:

```r
tmp <- tempfile()
dir.create(tmp)
cwd <- setwd(tmp)

pkgname <- "foo"
usethis::create_package(pkgname, rstudio = FALSE, open = FALSE,
                        fields = list(Imports = "mathjaxr", RdMacros = "mathjaxr"))
setwd(pkgname)
text <- "#' A title
#' 
#' \\loadmathjax{}
#' A description.
#' 
#' @param a,b Arguments.
#' 
#' @details
#' An irrelevant equation:
#' \\mjtdeqn{F(t) = \\left\\lbrace\\begin{array}{ll} \\alpha(t) f_{L}(t) + \\lbrack 1 - \\alpha(t) \\rbrack f_{C}(t)\\,, & t_{L} < t < t_{C}\\,, \\cr \\beta(t) f_{C}(t) + \\lbrack 1 - \\beta(t) \\rbrack f_{R}(t)\\,, & t_{C} < t < t_{R}\\,. \\end{array}\\right.}{%
#'           F(t) = \\begin{cases} \\alpha(t) f_{L}(t) + \\lbrack 1 - \\alpha(t) \\rbrack f_{C}(t)\\,, & t_{L} < t < t_{C}\\,, \\cr \\beta(t) f_{C}(t) + \\lbrack 1 - \\beta(t) \\rbrack f_{R}(t)\\,, & t_{C} < t < t_{R}\\,. \\end{cases}}{%
#'           ... a plain text translation ...}
#' 
#' @noMd
#' @export
#' @importFrom mathjaxr preview_rd
add <- function(a, b) a + b
"
cat(text, file = file.path("R", "add.R"))
roxygen2::roxygenize(".")
```

#### PDF output

```r
mathjaxr::preview_rd("add.Rd", type = "pdf")
```

[image]

#### HTML output

```r
mathjaxr::preview_rd("add.Rd", type = "html")
```

[image]

#### Plain text output

```r
mathjaxr::preview_rd("add.Rd", type = "txt")
```

[image]

#### A few remarks

- We are only escaping back slashes because we are typing the contents of `add.R` into a string. The text file created by `cat` does not contain the escapes.
- `\loadmathjax{}` injects a MathJax script into the HTML file. It is usually placed at the top of the description, so that you can typeset math everywhere after that.
- We are using macro `\mjtdeqn` to supply LaTeX for the PDF manual, LaTeX for the HTML help page, and plain text for the plain text help page, in that order. There are other macros that you can use in simpler cases. They are all documented in the [README](https://github.com/wviechtb/mathjaxr), which you should read carefully.
- In the PDF field, you do not have access to AMS extensions, so you have to implement `cases` yourself with `array`.
- In both the PDF and HTML fields, you need to use `\cr` in place of the usual `\\` in multiline environments. I'm not sure why.
- I haven't figured out how to encode line breaks in the plain text field (yet). It's going to be hard to translate multiline equations to plain text without line breaks...
- I disabled Markdown support for this header with `@noMd` because, in my experience, the Markdown parser doesn't always play nicely with the **mathjaxr** macros. In my own packages, I disable Markdown support globally via `DESCRIPTION`.
- You need `@importFrom mathjaxr preview_rd` somewhere in your package to circumvent `R CMD check` warnings about having **mathjaxr** in your `Imports` without using any functions exported by **mathjaxr**.
- To preview help pages that use MathJax without installing your package, you need to use `mathjaxr::preview_rd`. The **devtools** preview will show you unrendered LaTeX code.
- You'll have to decide whether MathJax support is worth having **mathjaxr** in your `Imports`. Anyone who tries to install your package is going to have to install **mathjaxr**, too.

#### Cleaning up

```r
setwd(cwd)
unlink(tmp, recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution and detailed remarks.

Answer (score 0):

Base on the solution of Mikael, a cleaner version:

```
#' A title
#'
#' @param a,b Arguments.
#'
#' @section options:
#' - `item1`:
#'    \mjtdeqn{
#'    F(t) = \left\lbrace\begin{array}{ll}
#'         \alpha(t) f_{L}(t) + (1 - \alpha(t)) f_{C}(t), & t_{L} < t < t_{C}, \cr
#'         \beta(t) f_{C}(t) + (1 - \beta(t)) f_{R}(t), & t_{C} < t < t_{R}. \end{array}\right.}{%
#'    F(t) = \begin{cases}
#'         \alpha(t) f_{L}(t) + (1 - \alpha(t)) f_{C}(t), & t_{L} < t < t_{C}, \cr
#'         \beta(t) f_{C}(t) + (1 - \beta(t)) f_{R}(t), & t_{C} < t < t_{R}. \end{cases}}{}
#'
#' - item2
#'
#' \loadmathjax{}
#' @export
#' @importFrom mathjaxr preview_rd
add <- function(a, b) a + b
```

> `Markdown` is compatible with `mathjaxr` in this example

```
mathjaxr::preview_rd("add.Rd", type = "pdf")
mathjaxr::preview_rd("add.Rd", type = "html")
```

Above scripts returns the same result as Mikael's.